# Javascript revealing module pattern, public properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, module-pattern

I'm trying to get my head round the revealing module pattern in javascript. I'm puzzled by two things about the following code snippet.

```
        var Child = function () {
            var totalPoints = 100;
            addPoints = function (points) {
                totalPoints += points;
                return totalPoints;
            };
            getPoints = function () {
                return totalPoints;
            };
            return {
                points: totalPoints,
                addPoints: addPoints
            };
        };
        $(function () {
            var george = Child();
            console.log(george.points);
            console.log(george.addPoints(50));
            console.log(george.points);
        });
```

1. The three values written to the console here are 100, 150, 100. That tells me that when I call "addPoints" with a value the totalPoints variable isn't updated. If I examine the value of totalPoints *within* the addPoints function it *has* been incremented properly. **What's going on?**
2. If I use the console to examine window.addPoints or window.getPoints I can see that because I haven't used "var" in front of the function declarations they've been added to the global scope. **Isn't that wrong?** Most of the examples I'm looking at seem to do this.

Any pointers gratefully received.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You're passing a number here:

```
return {
    points: totalPoints,
    addPoints: addPoints
};
```

This piece of code is no different from:

```
return {
    points: 100,
    addPoints: addPoints
};
```

You're passing the *value*; not a reference to `totalPoints` (the latter is not possible in JavaScript). So when `totalPoints` changes, the value in the object does not.

---

### Using a function

The simplest way to get around this is to use a function to get the most up-to-date result (like `getPoints` which you already have). [This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SwBLk/2/) gives a complete example:

```
return {
    points: function(x) { return totalPoints; }, // always up-to-date
    addPoints: addPoints
};
```

The downside is that the caller must now ask for `points` as a function call:

```
console.log(george.points());
```

---

### Using a getters and setters

Another solution is using *getters* which *would* enable you to get an updated value with just `george.totalPoints`, though getters are not widely supported (yet). You could implement a getter like this:

```
var obj = {};

obj.points = addPoints;

// add a "special" property to the object instead of normal notation
Object.defineProperty(obj, "totalPoints", {
    get: function() { // function that's executed when you use `.totalPoints`
        return totalPoints;
    }
});

return obj;
```

---

Secondly, dropping `var` makes the functions global which is correct but not advisable. You could make one `var` statement using commas, if that's what you mean:

```
var totalPoints = 100, // expands to three `var` statements, so no
    addPoints = ...,   // global variables
    getPoints = ...;
```

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful, so I made a post about it setters and getters are needed http://geekswithblogs.net/Aligned/archive/2013/01/15/setting-a-var-property-in-the-javascript-revealing-module-pattern.aspx. Hopefully it helps someone.

Comment: +1 finding a bug related to this was driving me crazy for the last 45 minutes now!

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly different solution, that doesn't require a getter/setter and preserves `totalPoints` as a property.

```
    var Child = function () {

        var _api;

        return _api = {

            addPoints: addPoints,
            points: 100
        };

        /* ----------- */

        function addPoints(points) {
            _api.points += points;
            return _api.points;
        };

    };
```

Comment: That provides a "getter like" field but not a setter - it is still a function.